# Что делать если лагает android эмулятор?

Tags: android-sdk, android, эмулятор, java

Всем привет. У меня проблема с андроид эмулятором устройства, он очень долго запускается и к тому же ужасно лагает. Проблему с запуском можно решить включением опции снапшота. А вот проблема с лагами пока никак не решена. Железо у меня весьма хорошее - AMD Athlon II x3 3.4GHz и 8гб памяти. Работать с этим совершенно невозможно. Что делать? В гугле решения не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите Android X86 в VirtualBox
http://habrahabr.ru/post/119931/
P.S. В посте описано как ставить андроид 2.2. Рекомендую качать самый последний андроид 4.2 - там LAN не нужно настраивать автоматом работает, а вот DHCP на eth1 делать придется. И размер диска 2Gb советую сделать, когда я делал диск 3-4Gb у меня флэшка не создавалась.

Comment: Я нереально в восторге от скорости виртуалки.

Comment: Ну а если захотите, чтобы Titanium Studio работал, то смотрите мой вопрос про Titanium Studio

Comment: Большое спасибо, @ReinRaus. Похоже, что это, то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы порекомендовал установить [Intel HAMX](http://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/146114/)

Сам очень доволен

Comment: Только человек придется поменять процессор и материнскую плату скорее всего.

Comment: ой, и  в правду :D ну у кого intel с поддержкой виртуализации, тому поможет

Answer (score 0):

Я использую реальный девайс через USB-шнурок. Грузится быстро, исполняется тем более.

Comment: Ну это да, но для реальных приложений, нужно протестировать как-минимум на нескольких типах девайсов, а у меня только 7 дюймовый планшет.

Answer (score 0):

Может стоит попробовать Bluestacks. Работает быстро, стабильно, единственный минус это android 2.x(не помню какой именно) отсюда все вытекающие (например ActionBar).

Answer (score -1):

Надо запустить 1 раз и не выключать эмулятор каждый раз по окончании сессии отладки.

Comment: @Barmaley все равно очень медленно. У меня андроид 4.0 в эмуляторе тормозил так, что мама не горюй. А в виртуалке 4.2 даже анимация плавно отрисовывается

Comment: Проблему с запуском можно решить включением опции снапшота. А вот проблема с лагами пока никак не решена. 

Внимательно надо читать вопрос.